# Python: mathematical operations

Tags: python, for-loop, operators

I want to creat a programa that reads two input numbers and do mathematical operations on them: addition, multiplication, division and subtraction.

I have this code:

```
sum=0
multi=0
div=0
sub=0

for i in range(1,3):
    num = int(input(f'{i}º dígito: '))
    sum+=num
    multi*=num
    div/=num
    sub-=num

print(f'Soma: {sum}')
print(f'Multi: {multi}')
print(f'Div: {div}')
print(f'Sub: {sub}')
```

The sum works well, but the others don't and I don't understand why. If I input 3 as the first number and 2 as the second number the sum is 5 (all good), but the multi prints 0, the div 0.0 and the sub -5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: O times anything will always be 0... Start with 1.

Comment: You should be careful naming variables `sum` too, Python uses this a keyword hence why your code snippet has `sum` as orange. Change it to total or something perhaps.

Comment: E. g. multiplying zero with anything remains zero. Better omit the for-loop, store the input values in two variables and do calculations with them.

Comment: The reason because `range` excludes the last value is precisely to allow for the more intuitive `range(2)` instead of `range(1,3)`. You can then use `{i+1}`in the prints. Think in a future yourself trying to adapt/debug this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, defining the variables as `0` from teh beginning and operating straightforward on them may cause problems because it will do things like `0 * num` or `0 / num`.

For only two inputs you don't need a loop. But if you want to loop anyway (let's say that you're considering adding the possibility of working with more inputs in the future), I would consider that the inputted values that you want to store are **1)** conceptually similar: they're all numbers inputted by the user that you'll use in the calculations; **2)** they have an order. So, the data type you need is probably a list.

```
num = []
i = 1
while i <= 2:
    num.append(int(input(f'{i}º dígito: ')))
    i += 1
    
soma = num[0] + num[1]
multi = num[0] * num[1]
sub = num[0] - num[1]

try:
    div = num[0] / num[1]
except ZeroDivisionError:
    div = "You can't divide by zero!"

print(f'Soma: {soma}')
print(f'Multi: {multi}')
print(f'Div: {div}')
print(f'Sub: {sub}')
```

Some other changes:

- `soma` instead of `sum` since `sum` is a reserved word. One that you may want to use if dealing with many inputs :)
- `while i <= 2` instead of for `for i in range(1,3)` for readability. This will come handy if you need to adapt the code (e.g. you could ask the user to input the value for `i`).
- `try` - `except` block to handle the case of division by zero.

To see why the list is a good holder here, let's suppose you allow the user to input more than two numbers. They introduce three numbers *x*, *y* and *z* and you want the division to output (*x*/*y*)/*z*. Then you can just loop over the values in your list:

```
div = num[0]
for i in range(1, len(num)):
    try:
        div /= num[i]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        div = "You can't divide by zero!"
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

multi: you start with 0, therefore `0*anything == 0`.

div:  you also start with 0, and `0/anything == 0`.

sub: looks right to me. `0-3-2 == -5`

I suspect what you want is to have the first number operated on using the second number. Your current set-up is using 0 operated on using the first number and then the second number.

```
first = int(input(f'{i}º dígito: '))
second = int(input(f'{i}º dígito: '))
summ = first + second #don't use sum as a variable name - its reserved in python
multi = first * second
sub = first - second
div = first / second
```

This I suspect is more like what you want. Be careful of `first==0` because your division will fail. Also, I'd look up "integer division" and its impact in Python because it might cause you some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

#Just add some lines

```
sum=0
multi=1
div=1
sub=0

for i in range(1,3):
    num = int(input(f'{i}º dígito: '))
    sum+=num
    multi*=num
    if (i==1):
        div = num
    if( i==2):
        div = div/num
    sub = -sub
    sub-=num

print(f'Soma: {sum}')
print(f'Multi: {multi}')
print(f'Div: {div}')
print(f'Sub: {sub}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

That's happening because when you do a operation like this `multi*=num` the python interpreter is doing this: multi = multi * num. If the variable multi starts with zero then: multi = 0 * num, and returns 0.

So, what's happening with each operatoration on the first iteration:

- Sum = 0 + num = num.
- Div = num / 0 = 0
- Multi = 0 * num = 0
- Sub = 0 - num = -num

You need to fix the first iteration of your code, and something like this will work:

```py
    sum=0
    multi=0
    div=0
    sub=0
    # creates a counter
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(1,3):
        num = int(input(f'{i}º dígito: '))
        # if it is not the first iteration them do the operation
        if count > 0:
            sum+=num
            multi*=num
            div/=num
            sub-=num
        # else sets everything equal num
        else:
            sum = num
            multi = num
            div = num
            sub = num
        # updates the counter
        count += 1
    
    print(f'Soma: {sum}')
    print(f'Multi: {multi}')
    print(f'Div: {div}')
    print(f'Sub: {sub}')
```

Comment: I think leaving the for loop in play is a little overkill.

Comment: For only 2 numbers I also think so, but if the ideia is to use with more inputs then the for loop is better

Comment: Yes, i know that 2 numbers doesn't justify the loop, but the idea is precisely if I wanna put more numbers don't have the need to creat more variables, so thank you very much for your solution @Otavio Maginador!

Comment: Great! Can you mark as solution later, please? Thank you, @DR8.